# How to compile and use php extensions on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-mojave

I have just installed the new OSX Mojave and as you know it comes with PHP 7.1.19 pre installed with just few extensions available.

First of all, I am not a fan of homebrew or any other package managers as well as disabling security utils i.e. csrutil.

I have successfully compiled intl extension but apache doesn't load it due to a code signing problem:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' - dlopen(intl.so, 0x0009): code signature in (intl.so) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed. in Unknown on line 0
```

Is there a way to sign the newly compiled extensions, probably using ad-hoc signing method or something?

I know there are lots of other topics about this issue but all are left unanswered or at most suggesting homebrew kind of workarounds!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days and days trying to get `intl` to work with the built-in php I ended up with a robust solution!

First I must say that this answer has nothing to do with code signing!

Here is what I have done, I ignored the built-in package( php, apache ) and compiled both from source and now I have the latest version of both installed with intl extension running like a charm, building new extensions is a piece of cake and php runs them without nagging :)

I don't really understand why people use `homebrew` for such a thing while you can easily compile libraries and extensions yourself.

I hope this answer helps someone out there.

Comment: To elaborate on this, I understand code signing is only **part** of the problem. Even if you do sign the code, with Catalina you'll end up with another issue (as described in https://superuser.com/a/1536442/1100783). Building PHP and the extension would solve the code signing issue.

Answer (score -3):

I also have same problem. Everybody resolves the problem with homebrew...

```
codesign -vd /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/x.so
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/x.so: code object is not signed at all


codesign -vd /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so 
Executable=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so
Identifier=com.apple.opcache
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=2914 flags=0x0(none) hashes=87+2 location=embedded
Platform identifier=5
Signature size=4485
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=68


codesign -vd /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so 
Executable=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
Identifier=com.apple.xdebug
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=1985 flags=0x0(none) hashes=58+2 location=embedded
Platform identifier=5
Signature size=4485
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=64
```

Comment: Does that mean you still have the problem? If so follow my instructions and compile php, apache from source and it'll be ok.

Comment: Sure, It's ready, but it does not solve the cause of file signature (the big problem)