# Install imagick extension in Mac OS Catalina : php_imagick.h:42:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, php-7.3

I've followed [these steps](https://ma.ttias.be/install-phps-imagick-extension-on-mac-with-brew/) to install `imagemagick` and php extension `imagick` in my computer with Mac OS Catalina and I can't seem to find a way.

I always get the following error when trying to install `imagick` with `$ sudo pecl install imagick`:

```
php_imagick.h:42:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I'm using `php.7.3.11`.

Apparently Mac OS X Catalina decided to move the headers to another folder and now it doesn't seem to find them.

I've been reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58384397/1081396) but seems like the solution is too long to be true. Isn't there any other more simple and straight forward method?

It seems others [manage to fix it for other extensions](https://affinitybridge.com/blog/adding-php-extensions-system-php-under-os-x-1015-catalina) with much less trouble. 
However, I'm not quite sure the steps for Imagick are exactly the same...

Comment: I didn't have any issue installing `imagick` on `macOS 10.15.4` using these instructions and `sudo pecl install imagick`. *`install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-3.4.4`* ; and I can see it if I run `php -m | grep -i magic`. Is this problem related just to `PHP 7.3`? I just `brew install php` and it got `PHP 7.4.4`.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue with my new MacBook Air and Catalina. It was a because I did not have PHP installed with `brew`. I looked at the page you linked to, and I am assuming you have already completed the `brew install pkg-config imagemagick`. This is what I would do to get clean it up and get it working, see below.

#### Remove your existing `imagemagick` and `pkg-config` that were just installed (and PHP if it shows up in the versions list)

First, we get the php @ver name if necessary. If you don't see PHP in the list then we don't need to remove it, just remove the other two.

```
    brew list --versions
    ...
    imagemagick 7.0.10-0
    ...
    pcre 8.44
    php@7.3 7.3.16
    pkg-config 0.29.2_2
    ...
```

#### Stop the php service if it is running, in my case it is @7.3

brew services stop php@7.3

#### Next we remove the items having issue

`brew remove php@7.3 pkg-config imagemagick`

or simply

`brew remove pkg-config imagemagick` *if PHP not installed with brew*

**Restart your computer (optional, but I like to do it)**

#### Now we install the items again, include PHP this time if it was not installed with brew last time

`brew install php@7.3 pkg-config imagemagick`

**Add PHP to your path for cmd line if not already there (optional)**

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

**To have launchd start php@7.3 now and restart at login:**

`brew services start php@7.3`

***Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:***

`php-fpm`

#### Confirm PHP and imagemagick and perl/pecl are the expected versions

`php -v`

```
PHP 7.3.16 (cli) (built: Mar 19 2020 11:19:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.16, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

`convert --version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-0 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-04 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

`pecl version`

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.10
PHP Version: 7.3.16
Zend Engine Version: 3.3.16
Running on: Darwin mbookair.local 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

#### Now install iMagick using pecl

`pecl install imagick`

*hit ENTER when you see the path question for 'autodetect'*

When it's complete you can confirm the module is loaded
`php -m | grep imagick`

*if it's loaded it will return one line with the word `imagick`*

**Test from command line imagick installed correctly**
cd to your user home dir
`cd ~`

**Run PHP as interactive shell from cmd line**

`php -a`

**Code to test at cmd line:**

```
$im = new Imagick ();
$im->newImage (300, 225, "blue");
$im->writeImage ("test_imagick.jpg");
```

*Exit php interactive mode by typing exit, then check if the bright blue test_imagick.jpg was created in your user dir*

#### Troubleshooting Notes

If you are getting a warning about:

```
"PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"
```

This may be left over from the previous pecl install that did not complete. Check your php.ini file and remove duplicate `extension="imagick.so"` entry

Comment: I can't believe it is soooo complicated to install... isn't there any other more human way? I feel like there's something very wrong with PHP if we have to do all this to install a simple extension.

Comment: My answer was longer because I was trying to provide instructions on how to unwind anything you may have done and then do a somewhat of a fresh install with a way to test from PHP at the cmd line to ensure imagick was installed and working. The short answer is: **1)** `brew install php@7.3`, **2)** `brew reinstall pkg-config imagemagick`, **3)** `pecl install imagick`. Does that work?

Comment: the same error will be shown when issuing `pecl install imagick`

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Worked for me. I've finally bit the bullet and moved Mac OS over to homebrew for php, much easier now!

Comment: for me just adding the two bash_profile lines worked with source .bask_profile

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in home brew, here is the link
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/41081

When you get tired of home brew, switch to Ubuntu, install imagick no fuss package installation.