# Manual configuration of Xcode

Tags: php, macros, libsodium

Upgraded to OSX Catalina and am having trouble installing libsodium for PHP. I have followed these steps [Installation of Xdebug on MacOS Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317736/installation-of-xdebug-on-macos-catalina-10-15) and still no joy.

When I run the `php -i | grep "xdebug support"` cmd I get the following error:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so:
dlopen(/usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so, 0x0009):
symbol '_xdebug_globals' not found, expected in flat namespace by'/usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so'
```

Any thoughts? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by following the instructions at this site

https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-catalina.html

The solution on the site above is more detailed in the php-config portion. I believe the previous solution still works, but this one does not require you to turn SIP off.