# PHPUnit always output "No tests executed!" on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, macos-big-sur

When trying to run **any** PHPUnit tests, I always get a `No tests executed!` message on my MacOS machine. A simple way to reproduce, on this specific machine, is to install a fresh instance of Laravel and running the default tests :

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
$ cd blog
$ vendor/bin/phpunit

=> No tests executed!
```

The expected output would be `OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)`.

As far as I know, **this is not a PHPUnit configuration issue** since the default Laravel code is expected to work, **the same issue appear with other framework and any code I try**, the same issue is present with different PHPUnit version (8.5 and 9.4) and the exact steps listed above return the expected output inside an Ubuntu VM as well as on another Mac running Catalina.

Actually, I suspect it is not a PHPUnit issue, **but more of a MacOS issue *or* a PHP configuration issue**, one that could manifest in other form later with another tool or project.

PHPUnit used to work fine on this machine, but it's been a couples weeks/months I didn't actually used it. The only thing that changed since I last (successfully) used any PHPUnit on this Mac as been upgrading to MacOS Big Sur and installing (then uninstalling) Homebrew.

The issue appears PHPUnit can't find any testsuite. Running `vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Unit` still output `No tests executed!` while, inside a fresh Laravel install, should output `Ok (1 test, 1 assertion)`.

So my question is : Is there anything else I can try to fix this before doing a fresh install of macOS Big Sur, and is anyone having the same issue?

### EDIT - Dec. 1st 2020

As per requested in comments, here is my `phpunit.xml` which is, as described above, [the default Laravel one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Again, this shouldn't matters, as **any** configuration returns the same result on this computer, even some that are known to work before, on other Mac and on other OS.

Running tests using artisan :

```
$ php artisan test --testsuite Unit
  No tests executed! 

  Time:   0.01s
```

Output of `vendor/bin/phpunit --list-suites` :

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --list-suites
PHPUnit 9.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Available test suite(s):
 - Unit
 - Feature
```

Output of `vendor/bin/phpunit -v --testsuite Unit`:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -v --testsuite Unit
PHPUnit 9.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)
Configuration: /Users/malou/Desktop/blog/phpunit.xml

No tests executed!
```

> N.B.: `/Users/malou/Desktop/blog/phpunit.xml` is the one displayed above.

Referencing files directly **works** :

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/Unit
PHPUnit 9.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.006, Memory: 8.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

### Edit #2 - Dec 1st 2020

More debug info for you :

```
$ php -v
WARNING: PHP is not recommended\nPHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.\nFuture versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Oct 30 2020 00:19:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.22, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1

### Edit - Dec 2nd 2020

In response to [PHPUnit always output "No tests executed!" on MacOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064182/phpunit-always-output-no-tests-executed-on-macos-big-sur#comment115098156_65064182):

I added the following:

```php
    public static function main(bool $exit = true): int
    {
        var_dump(ini_get("auto_prepend_file"));
        var_dump($_SERVER['argv']); die;
        return (new static)->run($_SERVER['argv'], $exit);
    }
```

When executing `vendor/bin/phpunit`:

```
/Users/malou/Desktop/blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:163:
string(0) ""
/Users/malou/Desktop/blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:164:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(18) "vendor/bin/phpunit"
}
```

When executing `vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Unit`

```
/Users/malou/Desktop/blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:163:
string(0) ""
/Users/malou/Desktop/blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:164:
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(18) "vendor/bin/phpunit"
  [1] =>
  string(11) "--testsuite"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "Unit"
}
```

Comment: N.B.: Reinstalling Homebrew and disabling XDebug didn't fix it.

Comment: 1. Try to run `php artisan test --testsuite Unit` 2. Add `cat phpunit.xml` to the question 3. Add `ls tests/Unit` to the question

Comment: 1. Similar as `phpunit --testsuite Unit` already addressed in question, artisan return nothing (and shouldn't matter much since artisan is a wrapper around phpunit). 2. See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml

Comment: What does `vendor/bin/phpunit --list-suites` output? And `vendor/bin/phpunit -v --testsuite Unit` Configuration file is `phpunit.xml`?

Comment: Lik @TotalPusher mentioned, check your phpunit.xml. Are they defined properly? probably paste it here, so that we can have a look. Also I guess you've done other bits as expected, like defining your test namespace in composer json, and extending them from phpunit TestCase class.

Comment: @TotalPusher See edit in question for result of those commands & phpunit.xml content

Comment: Okay, this is a tricky case. In the method `PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main();` I found this: `return (new static)->run($_SERVER['argv'], $exit);`. Please add `var_dump(ini_get("auto_prepend_file")); var_dump($_SERVER['argv']); die;` and show the result.

Comment: See edit. "auto_prepend_file" is empty and `argv` return the expected arguments

Comment: Found out why. It's Apple fault. Will write an answer when I manage a permanent fix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tl;dr** *Apple broke `version_compare` by naming PHP `7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)` in Big Sur. Installing another version of PHP fix this.*

---

I found the answer to my issue. It is indeed a MacOS issue, related to the built in version of PHP in MacOS Big Sur.

After quite some debugging (on another project using PHPUnit 8), I endend up here :
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/ccbf3962a948112056b0eded6e4c880af4ee3695/src/Util/Configuration.php#L1041-L1055

```
    private function satisfiesPhpVersion(DOMElement $node): bool
    {
        $phpVersion         = \PHP_VERSION;
        $phpVersionOperator = '>=';

        if ($node->hasAttribute('phpVersion')) {
            $phpVersion = (string) $node->getAttribute('phpVersion');
        }

        if ($node->hasAttribute('phpVersionOperator')) {
            $phpVersionOperator = (string) $node->getAttribute('phpVersionOperator');
        }

        return \version_compare(\PHP_VERSION, $phpVersion, (new VersionComparisonOperator($phpVersionOperator))->asString());
    }
```

When looking at the last line of PHPUnit code above (and since both `$node->hasAttribute('phpVersion')` and `$node->hasAttribute('phpVersionOperator')` return false), the return statement can be simplified to:

```
version_compare(\PHP_VERSION, \PHP_VERSION, '>=')
```

Now, because the version of PHP that ships with MacOS got deprecated in Big Sur, Apple renamed the version to `7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)`. This is what caused the issue, as the above code now become :

```
version_compare("7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)", "7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)", '>=')
```

**Which return false instead of true.**

A simple way to test :

```
$foo = version_compare("7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)", "7.3.22-(to be removed in future macOS)", '>=');
var_dump($foo); // bool(false)

$bar = version_compare("7.3.22", "7.3.22", '>=');
var_dump($bar); // bool(true)
```

That is probably because, as explained in the [official PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)...

> The function first replaces _, - and + with a dot . in the version strings and also inserts dots . before and after any non number so that for example '4.3.2RC1' becomes '4.3.2.RC.1'. Then it compares the parts starting from left to right. If a part contains special version strings these are handled in the following order: any string not found in this list < dev < alpha = a < beta = b < RC = rc < # < pl = p. This way not only versions with different levels like '4.1' and '4.1.2' can be compared but also any PHP specific version containing development state.

> Note that pre-release versions, such as 5.3.0-dev, are considered lower than their final release counterparts (like 5.3.0).

...the naming scheme of Apple is *probably* treated as a pre-release version inferior to itself instead of being equal to itself.

**So the fix would to overwrite the php version, which can't be done globally as far as I know. Installing another version of PHP using Homebrew seems the easiest solution**

Comment: wow, that's a good finding. It's very bad that apple broke the PHP like this where they could just have packaged it with a maintained version.

Comment: It turns out that the problem here is the close-paren at the end of the version string. When PHP normalizes the version number that winds up with an empty final component, and PHP's `version_compare` has a bug where both strings having an empty final component compares as less-than rather than equal.

Comment: What a ridiculous decision on Apple's part.